# Running a C web dyno in heroku?

Tags: c, heroku

Purely for fun I've written a tiny http server in C and using the c buildpack listed on the heroku docs, I've got it building a binary in heroku, and I can run it fine via "heroku run ./httpd 52132" It logs to the console "Starting httpd.." etc as expected but I obviously can't access it because thats a worker dyno, not a web dyno so isn't routed to.

My problem comes with I add a Procfile containing "web: ./httpd $PORT" - Heroku says its launched it, heroku ps shows its running but the requests timeout, and the application log never logs any messages from the app (I don't see Starting httpd...)

So in theory its running, but not running.... I'm confused.

As I said, it works when I don't run it via the procfile for web :(!!

Any ideas? (I know this is kind of niche!)

Thanks

Comment: try `heroku run bash`, and from within the shell try `./httpd $PORT` -- does that work?

Comment: yes, but then that is a dyno, and the port wont be forwarded from the router :(

Comment: Though this gave me an idea, I changed my Procfile to web: bash -c './httpd $PORT' and I get console output, saying its listening (as i expect) it just still doesn't get connections

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes, and also add `argv[1]` to your output, so you know you are listening on the correct port.

Comment: I think Heroku is sending a request with 0 bytes (maybe to see if the port is being listened on).. my crappy c code isn't handling this well and crashing I think ;)

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I think they do this by overriding `bind()`, mark marking the port as "listened to". I think there is something else going on.

Comment: Its definitely the case, started handling the empty connections by closing them properly, and not blocking, everything works fine..